# Alarm app is not accurate

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I m creating an Alarm app for android and for some reason there is always something like 20-60 sec delay in my alarms. I have no clue why is it happening as i m using the setExact() method for API 19+

My code:

```
private void setAlarm() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mHour = mTimePicker.getHour();
        mMinutes = mTimePicker.getMinute();
    } else {
        mHour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
        mMinutes = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinutes);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(EditAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EditAlarm.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Alarm Receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

public AlarmReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
}
```

Alarm Activity

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Vibrator mVibrator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


    // The ringing effects
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
    mVibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = { 0, 300, 200, 300, 100, 100 };
    mVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    // UI
    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    mVibrator.cancel();
                    finish();
        }
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: First, note that your `Calendar` code has a bug, as you are not handling the case where `mHour` is before now (e.g., it just turned noon where I am, so `mHour` of 0 through 11 is in the past). Beyond that, what is the exact hardware that you are testing this on, and how are you testing it? Bear in mind that many devices, including all running Android 6.0+, have features that will ignore or delay certain `AlarmManager`-scheduled events in the interests of saving battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixing the issue you need to set the seconds too. You need to set it to zero for firing it when the specified minute reaches:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinutes);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, i totally forgot about seconds!